# Keeping track of a list of items, even when items come and go: ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I had a hash of items, and I also kept the number of the largest key.

```
L = {1=>"item1", 2=>"item2", 3=>"item3"}, hi = 3
```

Then I removed the 1 entry

```
L = {2=>"item2", 3=>"item3"}, hi = 3
```

And now I wanted to add another item, but want to re-use deleted keys.
How can I re-design it to optimize the amount of time required to figure out which is the first available key?

I can always loop from 1 to `hi` and return the first key that is available, but even then maybe there's a fast way to write that rather than manually calling a loop and compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a more idiomatic Ruby way to write it than using an explicit loop.  Something like this:

```
first_available = ( 1 .. hi+1 ).find { |k| !L.include? k }
```

But the logic is the same.  Unless you use another variable to keep track of the minimum available key, you can't really avoid something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to avoid going 1-by-1, only to reduce the amount of numbers you have to go through.

For example, if you keep the lowest available number in a separate variable, after you add, all you have to do is check for the next lowest value starting at the key you just used.

In terms of performance, unless your hash will hold a few million keys, you shouldn't have to worry about having to look through each key in order. Even if you have 1 million keys in the hash, you can find the lowest value contiguously in well under 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, subclass or patch Hash and keep track of lowest available number (as well as highest taken number, or any other number you want). Something along the lines of

```
class MyHash < Hash
  # override
  def delete k
    @min_available ||= 0
    @min_available = k if k < @min_available
    # or you can have an array here to keep track of all freed slots
    #   if you want to sacrifice some memory for speed in this situation

    super k
  end

  def get_first_available
    # use @min_available to serve this request
  end
end
```

But then again, if you think you need to optimize something, you better have numbers to support that decision (hint: **profile and measure**).